# Mark files to Airflow such that it does not try to import them as DAG

Tags: airflow

I have the following structure

```py
airflow/
   |_dags/
      |_projects/
             |_utils/
             |_my_project/
                     |_tasks/
                          |_taskone.py
```

where `utils` contains several utils-files.

The issue is that airflow tries to import (just) one of the utils-files. I read somewhere, that Airflow treats files which contains the words `dag` and `airflow` in the same file (not filename!) as a DAG.

Since one of my utils-function `util1` has an absolute path e.g `airflow/dags/projects/utils` specified in it, I guess that is why `util1` is trying to be imported as a DAG (which clearly fails).

Is there a way to mark Airflow not to try import a specific file, like `util1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a file named `.airflowignore` and list what files/folders Airflow will ignore while processing DAGs. You can read about it in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#loading-dags):

> You can also provide an .airflowignore file inside your DAG_FOLDER, or
> any of its subfolders, which describes files for the loader to ignore.
> It covers the directory it's in plus all subfolders underneath it, and
> should be one regular expression per line, with # indicating comments.

Comment: I litterally serched for `airflowignore` 'cause I thought that would exist, but I cound'nt find it.  THanks